# Sqlalchemy - core - creating copy of an existing table

Tags: python, oracle, sqlalchemy

I need to create a table based on an existing table in the same (Oracle) schema. I don't want to have any constraint on the new table, even if original table may have one or more.

I have tried to create new table from the original table by using `column.copy()`, but for some reason, I am not able to drop the constraints after creating the new table in database.

```
def clone_table_approach_1(original_table, connection, metadata):
    try:
        new_table_name = original_table.name + '_sync'
        columns = [c.copy() for c in original_table.columns]
        new_table = Table(new_table_name, metadata, quote=False, *columns)

        # Create table in database
        if not new_table.exists():
            new_table.create()
        else:
            raise Exception("New table already exists")

        # Remove constraints from new table if any
        for constraint in new_table.constraints:
            connection.execute(DropConstraint(constraint))

        # Return table handle for newly created table
        final_cloned_table = Table(new_table, metadata, quote=False)
        return final_cloned_table

    except:
        # Drop if we did create a new table
        if new_table.exists():
            new_table.drop()
        raise
```

This fails while dropping the constraints. It seems sqlalchemy is not aware of names of the constraints created on new table in the database. I can see the new table with constraint names like "SYS_C00450822" and "SYS_C00450823" (these are NOT NULL check constraints).

Exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/gaurav/myprojects/python/sync/test_table_copy.py", line 163, in <module>
    t_product_new = clone_table_approach_1(t_product, target_conn, target_metadata)
  File "/home/gaurav/myprojects/python/sync/test_table_copy.py", line 57, in clone_table_approach_1
    connection.execute(DropConstraint(constraint))
  File "/home/gaurav/.local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 729, in execute
    return meth(self, multiparams, params)
  File "/home/gaurav/.local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/ddl.py", line 69, in _execute_on_connection
    return connection._execute_ddl(self, multiparams, params)
  File "/home/gaurav/.local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 777, in _execute_ddl
    compiled = ddl.compile(dialect=dialect)
  File "<string>", line 1, in <lambda>
  File "/home/gaurav/.local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/elements.py", line 493, in compile
    return self._compiler(dialect, bind=bind, **kw)
  File "/home/gaurav/.local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/ddl.py", line 27, in _compiler
    return dialect.ddl_compiler(dialect, self, **kw)
  File "/home/gaurav/.local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/compiler.py", line 199, in __init__
    self.string = self.process(self.statement, **compile_kwargs)
  File "/home/gaurav/.local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/compiler.py", line 222, in process
    return obj._compiler_dispatch(self, **kwargs)
  File "/home/gaurav/.local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/visitors.py", line 80, in _compiler_dispatch
    return meth(self, **kw)
  File "/home/gaurav/.local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/compiler.py", line 2518, in visit_drop_constraint
    self.preparer.format_constraint(drop.element),
  File "<string>", line 1, in <lambda>
  File "/home/gaurav/.local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/compiler.py", line 2928, in format_constraint
    return self.quote(constraint.name)
  File "/home/gaurav/.local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/compiler.py", line 2893, in quote
    if self._requires_quotes(ident):
  File "/home/gaurav/.local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/compiler.py", line 2864, in _requires_quotes
    lc_value = value.lower()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'lower'
```

Is there any other better approach to this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like I have solved my own question.

The original table had three "NOT NULL" constraints (not explicitly named, so they were named "`SYS_C00450822`" etc), and one PK constraint (Named as, say, "TABLE_PK").

When I was creating copy with just columns from original table, **but not constraints**, the new table was created with 4 constraints, all with system generated names like "SYS_C00450822".

While dropping the constraints, sqlalchemy didn't get any "name" for the constraints, as mentioned in the question, and somewhere down the line, that caused problems in line  `lc_value = value.lower()` because the value (which I think is the "name", is null, of NoneType).

So I changed the code to create new table with constraints too from the original table - but renaming the name of the constraint, so that it doesn't conflict with existing original table constraint).

This created three "NOT NULL" CHECK constraint in the same way, but the PK constraint was now **defined with name**, say, "TABLE_PK_2".

This then made safely through `DropConstraint` call.

I know I shouldn't have to do all this just to create a new table with original table definition, but for now, this seems to work.

Comment: Sure thing. But I will have to wait for 2 days before I could accept it.